# Как сделать импорт в SQL?

Tags: excel, sql-server, c#

Имеется SQL server 2005 и C#. Необходимо внести несколько записей с Excell в базу.
Я хочу скопировать эти записи в буфер и с помощью C# занести в Базу. Как это сделать? Спс заранее.

Answer (score 1):

1. открываете файл для чтения
2. выбираете нужные данные
3. соединяетесь с бд
4. заносите нужные данные.
    В чем конкретно затык?

Answer (score 1):

1. Правой клавишей на БД в SSMS
2. Import Data
3. выбираете source файл эксель
4. выбираете destination вашу бд
5. проверяете mapping
6. Run immediatly..

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сконвертировать данные в SQL команды с помощью AWK.

Предположим Вам нужно загрузить номера телефонов:

```
Иванов;Иван;Иванович;1965-01-01;+79272101010
Петров;Генадий;Николаевич;1980-01-18;+79272101894
Николаева;Жанна;Александровна;1991-12-24;+79273164132
```

Таблица contact в базе данных:

```
TABLE contact (
  id            bigint,
  type          varchar(1024),
  contact      varchar(1024),
  person_fk     bigint
)
```

AWK скрипт:

```
{
 last_name = $1
 first_name = $2
 middle_name = $3
 birth_date = $4
 phone_number = $5
}
{
 printf "INSERT INTO contact(id,type,contract,person_fk) \n \
    SELECT nextval('id_seq'), 'PHONE', '%s', person.id FROM person \n \
    WHERE \n \
            last_name = '%s' \n \
        and first_name = '%s' \n \
            and middle_name = '%s' \n \
            and birth_date = '%s' \n \
            and NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM contact WHERE \n \
                person_fk = person.id \n \
                and contact.type = 'PHONE' \n \
                and contact.contact = '%s' \n \
            ); \n \
",phone_number, last_name, first_name, middle_name, birth_date, phone_number
}
```

---

С помощью AWK можно быстро и эффективно [решать широкий круг задач](https://www.influunt.ru/awk-developer-arsenal)